# parse json in nodejs with : in the json keys

Tags: node.js, json

My nodejs code receives a response from a HTTP POST call which is in xml. I convert it to json using xml2js, and now I need to read this so as to get the data of one of the json keys.

This is how a part of my json data looks. I am trying to read this as follows:

```
var base64encoded = jsonxml."soapenv:Body".runReportResponse.runReportReturn.reportBytes;
```

However, when I run this i get the error message:

```
jsonxml."soapenv:Body".runReportResponse.runReportReturn.reportBytes;
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string.'
```

I have also tried by removing the double quotes, but then it gives exception to the colon (:) which appears in the data. How do I read such kind of data?

Entire json:

```
[
  {
    "Envelope": {
      "$": {
        "xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
        "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
        "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      },
      "Body": {
        "runReportResponse": {
          "$": {
            "xmlns": "http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService"
          },
          "runReportReturn": {
            "metaDataList": {
              "$": {
                "xsi:nil": "true"
              }
            },
            "reportBytes": "MzAwMDAwMDA0Mzk5ODEwLERDT0cgQ29ycG9yYXRlIEJVDQozMDAwMDAwMDk0ODE4MzEsREVMRlRMQUJfVVNfQlVTSU5FU1NfVU5JVA0KMzAwMDAwMDAzMDYyNTI1LERFTEhJVEVDSF9VU19CVVNJTkVTU19VTklUDQozMDAwMDAwMDMwNjE1ODMsREVMTFMgVVMgQlUNCjMwMDAwMDAwMzE3OTE0NixERUxNRkcgVVMgQlUNCjMwMDAwMDAxMDI1NDA1NyxESEMgQ29ycG9yYXRlDQo=",
            "reportContentType": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
            "reportFileID": {
              "$": {
                "xsi:nil": "true"
              }
            },
            "reportLocale": {
              "$": {
                "xsi:nil": "true"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the answer base on your new JSON (thank you!). It looks like the problem is maybe that each property in the JSON is really an array.

I'd suggest if you don't want this behaviour, to have a look at the explicitArray options in the xml2js *options* object setting it to *false*.
 e.g. :

```
explicitArray (default: true): Always put child nodes in an array if true; otherwise an array is created only if there is more than one.
```

This might simplify accessing properties!

```js
let response = [
  {
"Envelope": {
  "$": {
    "xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  },
  "Body": {
    "runReportResponse": {
      "$": {
        "xmlns": "http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService"
      },
      "runReportReturn": {
        "metaDataList": {
          "$": {
            "xsi:nil": "true"
          }
        },
        "reportBytes": "MzAwMDAwMDA0Mzk5ODEwLERDT0cgQ29ycG9yYXRlIEJVDQozMDAwMDAwMDk0ODE4MzEsREVMRlRMQUJfVVNfQlVTSU5FU1NfVU5JVA0KMzAwMDAwMDAzMDYyNTI1LERFTEhJVEVDSF9VU19CVVNJTkVTU19VTklUDQozMDAwMDAwMDMwNjE1ODMsREVMTFMgVVMgQlUNCjMwMDAwMDAwMzE3OTE0NixERUxNRkcgVVMgQlUNCjMwMDAwMDAxMDI1NDA1NyxESEMgQ29ycG9yYXRlDQo=",
        "reportContentType": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
        "reportFileID": {
          "$": {
            "xsi:nil": "true"
          }
        },
        "reportLocale": {
          "$": {
            "xsi:nil": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
];


console.log("Report bytes: ", response[0].Envelope.Body.runReportResponse.runReportReturn.reportBytes);
```

Comment: Hello Terry,I tried using the object["property"] however it still gives an error as
 {
  "message": "Custom Code Problem in callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'soapenv:Envelope' of undefined"
}

Comment: Yes,  i have removed the soapenv: part from the properties so that its easier to extract it but it still gives the same error

Comment: How can i paste the entire json message here? seems there is character limitation.

Comment: The character limit on questions is 30,000, maybe you have reached this?

Comment: i have now added the entire json to the question, can you please check now? not sure whats going wrong, should ideally be working

Comment: I tried accessing it as array, but it still gives same error. However, i just figured out something else.
Before accessing the properties i convert the xml to json using xml2js
`parseString(newmessage, function(error, result){
    if (error) {
        console.info("ERROR: " + error);
    }
console.info("RESULT: " + result);
jsonxml = result;

then 

base64encoded = jsonxml[0].Envelope[0].Body[0].runReportResponse[0].runReportReturn[0].reportBytes[0];`

Now here the console.info "RESULT" gives something like this. 
RESULT: [object Object] 
So im not sure what object Object means

Comment: Try console.info ("RESULT: " + JSON.stringify(result)); , this might show more!

Comment: Ohh my bad, so now i think im passing the correct type of data to base64encoded variable. Also i have set the explicit Array as false. 
{base64encoded = jsonxml.Envelope.Body.runReportResponse.runReportReturn.reportBytes;}
The json i get now is updated in the Question.

And it still somehow fails at Body

{
  "message": "Custom Code Problem in callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Body' of undefined"
}

Comment: Also if i log the variable base64encoded it says undefined.

base64encoded = jsonxml.Envelope;
console.log('base64encoded:' + base64encoded);

Comment: I've updated the answer, give it another try. We'll get this fixed I'm sure of it :)!